# Decimal to hexadecimal conversion code in C++

Tags: c++

I'm a complete newbie to C++ programming. I've been given the task to code decimal to hexadecimal conversion. This is what I've done so far.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    long dec;
    int rem;

    std::cout << "enter decimal number: ";
    std::cin >> dec;

    while (dec > 0) {
        rem = dec % 16;
        if (rem > 9) {
            switch (rem) {
               case 10: std::cout << "A"; break;
               case 11: std::cout << "B"; break;
               case 12: std::cout << "C"; break;
               case 13: std::cout << "D"; break;
               case 14: std::cout << "E"; break;
               case 15: std::cout << "F"; break;
            }
        }
        else {
            std::cout << rem;
        }
        dec = dec / 16;
    }
}
```

It gives answer backwards, like if I input a decimal number '650' it gives hexadecimal value `A82` when the answer should be `28A`. Can anyone suggest what I should do to correct it?

Comment: `iostream.h` hasn't existed since C++ standardisation in 1998. That's a long time ago.

Comment: `rem = dec % 16;` This is the problem. You're always examining the _low_ digits, on every iteration.

Comment: If the only thing that is wrong is that it is backwards surely you can think of something to **reverse** your situation ;)

Comment: If you learn to use a debugger and step through your code it will become very clear very quickly what the problem is.

Comment: What about using the [`std::hex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex) I/O manipulator? Also note that `dec` already is a symbol used in the `std` namespace (not an actual problem with your code).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ From the wording of the question it sounds like an assignment of some kind that is probably not looking for a simple solution. Maybe the OP can clarify.

Comment: @mathematician1975 Sure, I'm just going to bother them a bit :) ...

Comment: Unfortunately many answers here fail when `dec == 0`, `dec < 0`, `dec` outside `int` range.

Answer (score 7):

The most simple solution:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int val;
    cin >> val;
    cout << hex << val << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The fix of your algorithm - use recursion:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

void print_hex(int value)
{
    if (value == 0)
        return;

    int rem = value % 16;
    value /= 16;
    print_hex(value); //first execute recurency and print next value

    //after return print the less significant digit
    if (rem > 9)
        cout << (char)(rem - 10 + 'A');
    else
        cout << rem;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    cout << "enter decimal number: ";
    long dec;
    cin >> dec;
    print_hex(dec);
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you mean "recursion" not "recurrence".

Comment: oh heck no.  Don't make him do a recursion algorithm for his first attempt.  That's just mean.

Comment: `main` returns `int`. Always. Not nothing and not `void`.

Comment: I copied the first version of the author code. But you're right there should be `int main`.

Comment: This solution has a bug, if input 0, then it will print nothing(return if value==0).  better to change it to iteration instead of recursion.

Comment: Fails when `value <= 0` and when called with `dec > INT_MAX`.

Answer (score 6):

Of course it gives the answer backwards. Your program starts analizing the given decimal number "starting from the back". To be specific, you are converting the number starting with the *least important* digits. After each digit processed you output it immidiately. Thus you first output the least important digits, but both hexadecimal and decimal systems represent number starting with the most important ones. In other words if your number is `XYZ` in hexadecimal (which represents `16^2 * X + 16^1 * Y + 16^0 * Z` in decimal), you output it as `ZYX`. Try saving all digits in a string, adding new digits in the beggining of it:

```
string s = "";
while (dec > 0)   // Do this whilst the quotient is greater than 0.
{
  rem = dec % 16; // Get the remainder.
  if (rem > 9)
  {
    // Map the character given that the remainder is greater than 9.
    switch (rem)
    {
      case 10: s = "A" + s; break;
      case 11: s = "B" + s; break;
      case 12: s = "C" + s; break;
      case 13: s = "D" + s; break;
      case 14: s = "E" + s; break;
      case 15: s = "F" + s; break;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    s = char(rem + 48) + s; // Converts integer (0-9) to ASCII code.
    // x + 48 is the ASCII code for x digit (if 0 <= x <= 9)
  }
  dec = dec/16;
 }
 if (s == "") // if the number was 0, the string will remain empty
   cout << "0";
 else
   cout << s;
```

Comment: This is probably the best answer, although reformatting the code wouldn't have hurt!

Comment: Of course it wouldn't. I was just focusing on correctness of this code instead of its aesthetics or good programming fashion.

Comment: Why can't we have _both_! :)

Comment: Special test `if (s == "") cout << "0";` not needed if `while (dec > 0) { ...}` changed to `do { ...} while (dec > 0);` and `dec <0` accounted for.

Answer (score 2):

If the only thing wrong is that the output is in the reverse order of what you want, you could place the output into a container instead. Then, reverse the order of the output in the container before printing it out.

One way to do to get the output into a container is to send your output to a `stringstream`.

```
std::ostringstream sout;
const char *hex = "0123456789ABCDEF";
while (dec > 0) {
    rem = dec % 16;
    sout << hex[rem];
    dec = dec / 16;
}
std::string s(sout.str());
std::reverse(s.begin(), s.end());
std::cout << s;
```

Comment: Prints nothing when `dec == 0`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yes, I followed the behavior spec for 0 case from OP.

Answer (score 2):

The solution if you want to convert from Decimal to Binary (Base 2), Hexadecimal (Base 16) etc!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void d2base(int n, int b);
char arr[] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};

int main()
{
    int num, base;

    cout << "Enter decimal number to convert: ";
    cin >> num;
    cout << "Enter the base: ";
    cin >> base;
    cout << "\nNumber in " << base << " is ";

    d2base (num, base);
}

void d2base(int n, int b)
{
    if (n > 0)
    {
        d2base(n/b, b);
        cout << arr[n%b];
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way: Put it into a string:

```
string answer = "";
while (dec > 0) {
    rem = dec % 16;
    if (rem > 9) {
        switch (rem) {
           case 10: answer = "A" + answer; break;
           case 11: answer = "B" + answer; break;
           case 12: answer = "C" + answer; break;
           case 13: answer = "D" + answer; break;
           case 14: answer = "E" + answer; break;
           case 15: answer = "F" + answer; break;
        }
    }
    else {
        answer = string(1, (char)rem-'0') + answer;
    }
    dec = dec / 16;
}
cout << answer;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm working now with MFC Cpp, and using CString:

```
CString hex;
hex.Format("%x", 16766208); //ffd500 - use capital %X for FFD500
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
/*  decimal /hexa
    Jose Anilto
*/
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>


using namespace std;


string converte(int n, string x) {

    string hexa = {"0123456789ABCDEF"};
    return (n < 16 ? "0x" + (hexa[n] + x) : converte(n/16, hexa[n%16] + x));

}

int main () {

    int nd ;
    string y = "";
    cout << "\n Digite um numero: "; cin >> nd;
    cout << "\n Numero digitado: " << nd << "\n";

    cout << "\n Hexadecimal: " << converte(nd, y) << "\n";

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Fails when `n < 0`.  Suggest `unsigned n`.

Comment: Verdade. Só vale para inteiros positivos.

Answer (score 1):

> to code decimal to hexadecimal conversion.

Without resorting to recursion it is simply enough to form the answer in a local buffer of the max possible size and populate it backwards.

This task is too rewarding for a code dump.  Posing an algorithm to guide instead.

```
  // Pseudo code
  long x
  L = MaxSizeNeeded(long) // hint:sizeof
  buffer[L]
  pointer p = last_element(buffer)
  *p = 0 // null character
  do {
    extract least base 16 digit of `x`
    *--p = text version of least digit
    x /= base
  } while (x)
  prepend "0x" if desired.
  Form string from `p` and return
```

Additional concerns involve when `x < 0`.  Either move code to `unsigned long` or to form "-0x1B" from input -27, fold values to the negative side, convert as above knowing least digit will be negative, and lastly applying a sign as needed.

Answer (score 0):

This code works greatly,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    long long int x;
    cin >> x;
    cout << hex << x;
    return 0;
}
```

If you want 0x in front of the converted number then this will work:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    long long int x;
    cin >> x;
    cout <<"0x"<< hex << x;
    return 0;
}
```