# Decimal to Hex - Reversing Hex Value

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, hex, reverse

I need to call byteSwap() with an int, then convert it to hexadecimal and reverse the hexadecimal. Ex. byteSwap(2030), or 7ee, in hex should return ee7. This program does some other things as well, and I would like to reverse in byteSwap() using reverse(). I've tried using several different loops inside byteSwap() but can't seem to get the hex value to actually reverse.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

void putInOrder(string *s1, string *s2);
void copy(int *f, int *t, int n);
void reverse(char *x, int n);
int byteSwap(int i);

int main() {

string a = "A";
string z = "Z";
auto *s1 = (string *) "A";
auto *s2 = (string *) "Z";
putInOrder(&z, &a);


int arr1 [3] = {3,4,5};
int arr2 [3] = {6,7,8};
int n;
cout << "Enter a number of values to be copied: ";
cin >> n;
copy(arr1,arr2,n);


char x = 0;
string name = "Computer";
reverse(&name[0],9);



byteSwap(2030);



return 0;
}
void putInOrder(string *s1, string *s2)
{
cout << s1 << " " << s2 << endl;

if(s2 > s1)
{
    swap(s1,s2);
}
else if (s1 > s2)
{
    cout << s1 << " " << s2 << endl;
}
cout << s1 << " " << s2 << endl;

}

void copy(int *f, int *t, int n)
{

for(int i = 0; i <= n + 2; ++i)
{
    t[i+3] = f[i];
    cout << t[i] << " ";
}
cout << "\n";
}

void reverse(char *x, int n)
{

for(int i = n - 1; i >=0; --i)
{
    cout << x[i] << "";
}
cout << "\n";
}

int byteSwap(int i)
{





}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decimal to hexadecimal conversion code in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29759404/decimal-to-hexadecimal-conversion-code-in-c)

Comment: Converting decimal to hexadecimal is not my main issue, therefore not a duplicate.

Comment: So, What is the main problem ? Reversing a hexadecimal is a problem.Please clarify

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Do you want to reverse the `char` array pointed to by `x`? Values are values, whether represented by decimal, octal, binary or hexadecimal literals.

Comment: 2030 is **0**7ee, so should the reversed be ee**0**7 and not ee7?

Comment: It will be ee70 @KillzoneKid

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `std::bitset` as it provides some useful methods for this kind of data manipulation. Here I took binary representation and reversed every 4 bits to get desired output (reverse every 8 bits to get `ee07`). You can tweak the size of bitset too to suit your needs:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

int main()
{
    std::bitset<16> num(2030);
    std::string numstr(num.to_string());

    std::string numstrrev;
    for (size_t i = 0, n = numstr.size(); i < n; i+=4)
        numstrrev = numstr.substr(i, 4) + numstrrev;

    std::bitset<16> numrev(numstrrev);

    std::cout << std::hex << numrev.to_ulong() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/ZuxKYE